# UIImagePicker and Camera in UITabBar popup for iPad

Tags: camera, uitabbarcontroller, picker, photolibrary

I wan't to include in my recent development a popup which shows a UITabBarcontroller with two tabs, one for the photolibrary and the second one for the camera. I don't want to use fullscreen for the camera, the popover will be something like 600x800 pixels and both, camera and library should be shown in these bounds. I have seen that some apps, like Facebook are doing this. How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I have changed both UIViewControllers from the UITabBarController to UIImagePickerController. For the second one, I added in the ViewDidLoad:

self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

Now I have in the first TAB the Library and chose any photo and the second TAB opens the camera and I can take photos.

STILL TO SOLVE:

First Controller is in the size I have dimensioned, 600x800, but when changing to the second (the camera) is resizes to something about 200x400. working on it to solve.